# Why I can not use exported routes in index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I receive an error.
React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

I am trying ti use riutes from import  in Index.js

```
    import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import routes from './routes.js';
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router-dom'; 

const renderApp = (appRoutes) => {
    ReactDom.render(appRoutes, document.getElementById('app'));
};

renderApp( routes() );
```

I export this routes from routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './components/App';

const routes = () => (

    <AppContainer>
            <Router history={browserHistory} component={App}>


            </Router>

    </AppContainer>

);

export default routes;
```

Comment: We really need to see `routes.js` to properly diagnose what's going on

Comment: You can see upstairs

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to call `routes`:

```
renderApp( routes() );
```